# Run WCID With Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, command-line-interface, networkmanager

I run into a typical problem with *Python* and version 2 vs. 3. More in detail I like to use `wcid-curses` to manage my network interfaces. Installing it from the official *Ubuntu 16.4* repositories seems to be written for *Python 2.x*. Per default I've configured to use version 3.5. If I run `wicd-curses` (or also not as curses application), I run into the following error message:

```
File "/usr/share/wicd/curses/wicd-curses.py", line 1280
  print 'Error connecting to wicd via D-Bus. ' \
                                           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

This looks for me like a typical *Python 2* vs *3* problem. So how can I make it running with the correct version, but leave my default configured version untouched? I tried some useless stuff, but didn't see a solution so far, cause I don't know how to define the *Python* version to run this command line command.
Any hints how to handle such a problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the module and test again , or do the new updates..
Or , Try to Open The Module and Write:

```
from pprint import *
```

or

```
import pprint
```

Comment: I installed it a few hours before the question was posted.

Comment: try to open the module and write import pprint or from pprint import *

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I just run it with python 2 now. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this question was too easy. A look with `whereis wicd` offers the location in `sbin/wicd` where the *Python* link is used to execute the scripts. I just adjusted this calls to use the respective *Python* version and save it. Now it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I found this this question several years and it was fitting to my problem.  I installed update-alternatives on my debian linux to be able to switch between python versions. But installing this package moved all relevant system links to

```
usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python
```

So wicd seems to be a python 2.X app and produced the error weilbith was describing. As weilbith suggested I only changed two bash files which are actually calling the python scripts:

```
/usr/sbin/wicd
and
/usr/bin/wicd-gtk
```

change

```
exec /usr/bin/python
```

to

```
exec /usr/bin/python2.7
```

(or your installed python2.X version)
This solved the issue on my system problem.